# 13.10 64bit install problem: Kernel Panic - not syncing

Tags: 13.10, kernel, ssd

I'm trying to install 13.10 64bit on my new laptop with a live CD, and I get the message:

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
drm_kms_helper: panic occured, switching back to text console
```

Only thing special with the laptop is that it has an SSD. 
Any idea what I can try next?

Any  help would be appreciated.

Comment: Still reproducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make a new live CD. 
  It could help to make a boot-Stick (maybe your cd-writer is not ok).

What is the name of your laptop?

Anyway 32-bit works everytime. You could try this.

Your last chance would be a modified live-cd.

Is it working after trying this even not, stay at 12.04.